# when my Main View render a Partial view which have its own Scripts ,the "'$' is undefined," error will occur

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

My problem is that I have Scripts inside my Partial view that are raising the following error:-

```
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
Server, line 336 character 9
```

I have the following Main view, which will render the PartialView:-

```
@model IPagedList<TMS.Models.TMSRack>

<div><span class="b"> There are @Model.TotalItemCount Racks.</span></div>
@Html.Partial("_PagedRackTable2",Model)
<i class=" icon icon-blue icon-star-on "></i> IT360 Data
    @section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DCSort").click(function () {
                //$("#iconSort1").hide();
                $("#progressSort1").show();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Index","Rack")",

                    data: { searchTerm: "@ViewBag.searchTerm.ToString()", page: "1", sort: "@ViewBag.DCSortPam", pagesize: $("#FilterSize").val() },

                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

                function successFunc(data, status) {     
                    $("#RackTable").html(data);
                    $("#progressSort1").hide();
                    //$("#iconSort1").Show();
                }

                function errorFunc() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            })

        });
    </script>
```

The `_PagedRackTable2` partial view looks as follow:-

```
@model IPagedList<TMS.Models.TMSRack>
<div id ="RackTable">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#DCSort").click(function () {
                //$("#iconSort1").hide();
                $("#progressSort1").show();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "Get",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Index","Rack")",

                    data: { searchTerm: "@ViewBag.searchTerm.ToString()", page: "1", sort: "@ViewBag.DCSortPam", pagesize: $("#FilterSize").val() },
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    //cache: false,
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

                function successFunc(data, status) {
                    $("#RackTable").html(data);
                    $("#progressSort1").hide();
                    //$("#iconSort1").Show();
                }

                function errorFunc() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            })
         });
    </script>
    <div class="SmallDropDown3 b" >
```

The error will occur when; I first render the main view, which will render the patrial view and the error occur. While If I return the partial view directly (for example after doing some paging), the Scripts on the partial view will not raise any error.

My indication for the problem is as follow:-

1. Inside my Layout view I have specified to run the Scripts inside the  `@section Scripts {` , so when the main view is rendered the partial view scripts will run before the Jquery is called from the layout view, since in my layout view the Scripts will run after rendering the body as follow:-

> @RenderBody()
>
> ```
> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
>
> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
>
> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custome")
>
> @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
> ```

But when I do a paging the Jquery files will already be loaded and that why the partial view Scripts will not raise an error.

To overcome this problem I have copies the Partial view Scripts to my main view as shown above (the same script is being added twice), this will allow my Scripts to run always , but still I will get the followign error on the partial views scripts when the main view is rendering the partial view.

```
SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
Server, line 336 character 9
```

Can anyone advice how I can overcome this problem ?

Thanks

Comment: your jquery library coflicting make sure jquery is not included multiple times e.g in main view and also in partial view

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I am only referencing jQuery ontime inside my Layout view, but i have the same javascript created twice for the reason i have included, so no jQuery conflict will ocurr i think ..

Comment: what's this:@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") in main view?